# jQuery Linked Selectors Not Showing? - What's wrong with this snippet?

Tags: jquery, debugging

Why isn't this snippet showing "YES" in the `div id = debug` after

1. each item in `id=box` is clicked and placed in `id=que`.  (assigned class `click2Remove`)
2. then clicked again in que?

?

```
<script>
var idcurrent = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".click2Select").click(function() {
        idcurrent = this.id;

        $("#" + idcurrent).attr("class", "removed");
        var s = '<a href="" onclick="return false" id="' + idcurrent + '" class="click2Remove">' + $("#" + idcurrent).html() + '</a>';
        $("#que").append(s);
        $("#debug").html("selected and in que: "+idcurrent);
    });
});
$("#que").delegate("click2Remove", "click", function() {
    $("#debug").html("YES");

});​
</script>

<div id="box">
    <li><a class="click2Select" onclick="return false" href="#" id="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="click2Select" onclick="return false" href="#" id="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="click2Select" onclick="return false" href="#" id="3">3</a></li>    
</div>

<div id="que">
</div>

<div id="debug">
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWD9J/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) selector needs a tweak, the class selector needs a `.`, like this:

```
$("#que").delegate(".click2Remove", "click", function() {
```

[Here's the version with a `.`, working](http://jsfiddle.net/HWD9J/1/) :)

Comment: yes thanks - just realized that as i was editing to format for stackoverflow.. (doh!!)

Answer (score 0):

Ack, forgot the . in the delegate... mea culpa!!